# How to compose two images using Magick.net

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, magick.net

Im currently trying to compose two blob images from my Azure Storage using Magick.net

Its almost working. But I think I just need some little fine tuning which I dont know how to do it.

Image1 = Main (Background)
Image2 = Overlay

Routine:
Image2 is actually a peninput with a black background. So I need to make the background from black to transparent and resizing to the same size as Image1.
After this I use a function to composite Image2 over image1.

This is my function but it does not work

```
        public MagickImage ComebineBitmap(MagickImage Main, MagickImage Overlay)
    {
        Main.Composite(Overlay);
        Overlay.Resize(Main.BaseWidth, Main.BaseHeight);
        Overlay.Transparent(MagickColors.Black);
        Main.Composite(Overlay);
        return Main;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public MagickImage ComebineBitmap(MagickImage Main, MagickImage Overlay)
    {
    MagickGeometry gm = new MagickGeometry();
    gm.Width = Main.Width;
    gm.Height = Main.Height;
    gm.IgnoreAspectRatio = true;

        Overlay.Density = Main.Density;
        Overlay.BitDepth(Main.BitDepth());

        Overlay.LiquidRescale(gm);
        Overlay.Transparent(MagickColors.Black);

        Main.Composite(Overlay, CompositeOperator.SrcOver);

       return Main;
    }
```